# How do I use pandas groupby() to show the value of 2 things per one column?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

So I have been trying to use pandas to create a DataFrame that reports the number of graduates working at jobs that do require college degrees ('college_jobs'), and do not require college degrees ('non_college_jobs').
note: the name of the dataframe I am dealing with is recent_grads

I tried the following code:

```
df1 = recent_grads.groupby(['major_category']).college_jobs.non_college_jobs.sum()
```

or

```
df1 = recent_grads.groupby(['major_category']).recent_grads['college_jobs','non_college_jobs'].sum()
```

or

```
df1 = recent_grads.groupby(['major_category']).recent_grads['college_jobs'],['non_college_jobs'].sum()
```

none of them worked! what am I supposed to do? can somebody give me a simple explanation regarding this? I had been trying to read through pandas documentations and did not find the explanation wanted.

here is the head of the dataframe:

```
   rank  major_code                                      major major_category  \
0     1        2419                      PETROLEUM ENGINEERING    Engineering   
1     2        2416             MINING AND MINERAL ENGINEERING    Engineering   
2     3        2415                  METALLURGICAL ENGINEERING    Engineering   
3     4        2417  NAVAL ARCHITECTURE AND MARINE ENGINEERING    Engineering   
4     5        2405                       CHEMICAL ENGINEERING    Engineering   

   total  sample_size    men  women  sharewomen  employed      ...        \
0   2339           36   2057    282    0.120564      1976      ...         
1    756            7    679     77    0.101852       640      ...         
2    856            3    725    131    0.153037       648      ...         
3   1258           16   1123    135    0.107313       758      ...         
4  32260          289  21239  11021    0.341631     25694      ...         

   part_time  full_time_year_round  unemployed  unemployment_rate  median  \
0        270                  1207          37           0.018381  110000   
1        170                   388          85           0.117241   75000   
2        133                   340          16           0.024096   73000   
3        150                   692          40           0.050125   70000   
4       5180                 16697        1672           0.061098   65000   

   p25th   p75th college_jobs  non_college_jobs  low_wage_jobs  
0  95000  125000         1534               364            193  
1  55000   90000          350               257             50  
2  50000  105000          456               176              0  
3  43000   80000          529               102              0  
4  50000   75000        18314              4440            972  

[5 rows x 21 columns]
```

Comment: Could you share at the least the head of this dataframe?

Comment: can you provide some sample dataframe and desired output?

Comment: @Anwarvic I have edited and showed the head of the dataframe in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the initial DataFrame by the columns you're interested in and then perform the groupby and summation as below:

```
recent_grads[['major_category', 'college_jobs', 'non_college_jobs']].groupby('major_category').sum()
```

Conversely, if you don't perform the initial column filter and then do a `.sum()` on the `recent_grads.groupby('major_category')` it will be applied to all numeric columns possible.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I finally found the solution. Could you probably explain it a little bit more detail on why it works?

Comment: @Ninawang I can try - when you perform DataFrame.groupby() you're essentially asking Pandas to perform a 'split-apply-combine' on the data in question.

In this case we want to split the DataFrame into groups of each 'major_category', apply a summation function across all of the data in the 'college_jobs' and 'non_college_jobs' columns, and combine the data back into a readable structure.

The [groupby Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html) has detailed description.

Comment: is it the same thing as recent_grads.groupby(['major_category'])['college_jobs', 'non_college_jobs'].sum() ?

Comment: Yep, the same thing! Because if I remember correctly when you do `recent_grads.groupby('major_category')` nothing is actually executed until you call some form of aggregation, such as the `.sum()`. Might need to check that in docs though.